# Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) (CWE ID 80)(1 flaw)

Tags: visualforce, xss

In my page even I have applied JSENCODE in few places to fix the flaw. But no luck. Still it is showing the flaw. Can anyone please help where it is exactly causing flaw.

```html
<apex:page standardController="Debt_Pricing_Template__c" extensions="RestViewOnDPT" >
    <script>
        if({!showDptPage}==true){
            if({!Debt_Pricing_Template__c.Is_New_Template__c}==true){
                window.location.href='/apex/DPTView?id={!JSENCODE(Debt_Pricing_Template__c.id)}';
            }
            else{
                window.location.href='/apex/DPTView_Old?id={!JSENCODE(Debt_Pricing_Template__c.id)}';
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('The record you tried to access is restricted for public view. Please contact ' + '{!JSENCODE(DptOwnerName)}');
            window.location.href='/home/home.jsp';
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Veracode static analyser for scan.

**Why is this error reported ?**

- This issue is reported since the variable passed would cause a change in rendered HTML.

More info - https://community.veracode.com/s/question/0D53n00008A802aCAB/fix-cwe-80improper-neutralization-of-scriptrelated-html-tags-in-a-web-page-basic-xssin-binary-data

**Solution**

- As inferred it's just the id which is being used , you can use `HTMLENCODE` instead of `JSENCODE` for fixing this.

More info - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_htmlencode.htm&type=5

Article about unescaped output in Visualforce page - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/pages_security_tips_scontrols.htm

Comment: Yes This flaw is generated in Veracode Scan only. I have used HTMLENCODE in place of JSENCODE . But still the flaw is coming up. any other suggstion pls ?

Comment: Ideally , HTMLENCODE should have fixed this. But try with - JSINHTMLENCODE